# Hydroponic spearmint are turning brown - what can I do?

Tags: diagnosis, hydroponic, mint

[image]

These were beautiful last week. What do I need to watch for?

Comment: Can you clarify please - you mention hydroponic mint, but the picture seems to show a mint plant in soil

Comment: It is not soil. Is mounted on an organic soft material inside a tower garden. Is getting a drip of water every 30 minutes.

Comment: What are the readings of your hydroponic mixture?  PH, EC/ppm and temperature?